# How to access Active Directory from remote machine in c#

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I want to know is it possible to access my client Active Directory from my cloud application which is developed in C#. If yes then please provide the solution

Answer (score 1):

Assuming required network connectivity is available, yes. What "required network connectivity" entails depends on the actual access mechanism being used. As an example, accessing Active Directory via secure LDAP requires TCP port 636 be open from the source to the domain controller.

Since it's not always feasible/practical/"a good idea" to open ports between cloud hosting sources and Active Directory domain controllers, you can look into ADFS (Active Directory Federation Services) which is a federated identify framework you can expose to the Internet and then use from within client applications (and we've got a good number of third party vendors that support authentication and directory data retrieval through ADFS as well).

As to the solution -- there are examples all over the Internet. Search here, search Github, search the Internet in general.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. I will try